# JQuery DataTable+ajax+struts2+json

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

Good day everyone. I have a web application built on java+struts2. In one of my webpage I have used JQuery tabs and In one of the tabs I am trying to populate the table with so many records which I fetch from DB. After 2 days of google search I have decided to go with JQuery Data table to populate the table with pagination. I am new to JQuery and Ajax. I have so many doubts in doing that. I am unable to find sample tutorial/example which does this work.

HTML :

```
<div id="ViewIncome">
    <table id="IncomeTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>
</div>
```

Struts.xml

```
<action name="refreshData" class="com.hibernate.action.UserIncomeAction" method="dataRefresh">
        <result type="json"></result>
</action>
```

Action Class Method:

```
//Income class variables are 'incomeID','amount','description' etc.,
private List<Income> incomesList;

public String dataRefresh()
{
    if(checkUserLogin())
    {
        //code to fetch the latest data from DB;
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    else
    {
        return LOGIN;
    }
}
```

JQuery: Updated Code.

```
 $("#IncomeTable").dataTable({
    "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
    "bProcessing" : false,
    "bServerSide" : false,
    "sAjaxSource" : "refreshData",
    "bJQueryUI" : true,
    "aoColumns" : [
{ "incomesList": "amount" },
{ "incomesList": "description" }
]
} );
```

Now How do I iterate the  `List<Income> incomesList;` in the above JQuery code. Also let me know if I need to add any additional lib/jar if I have to use the datatable. I have JQuery-Ui lib placed in my project.

Can some One help me with the link's or examples in achieving my desired output.

[image: Data table]

Comment: Check this example https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details.html

Comment: @goodyzain: how did the "data" json object has the data as show in ajax tab of the above mentioned link?

Comment: I have updated my code and the attached the Image. Issue is the table is not getting populated in the desired location(view incomes tab of the page) and the 2nd issue is there were no data populated in the table

Answer (score 0):

Some of the struts2 I was a little problem, I think there should be a new package